# vertical align middle on floating div. Container got min-height

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have some problems align my elements vertically to middle on floating Divs.
I can't use line-height, cause there is text that can be on 2 lines. The container got a `min-height`. But I don't get it to work. I created a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/gdggo6x5/

I need the float, cause in lower resolution the image shall be under the text (I use media querys for that).

I also tried to use `display: table-cell` on `footer2_block1` and `block2`:

```
 min-height: 72px;
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: middle;
```

But this does not the trick. Anyone got a tip for me how to set all the Elements to middle?

Comment: if you know both the containing and the contained elements' height, use `margin-top`, or `top` and `position: absolute`. Otherwise, you'll need javascript

Comment: can not use margin-top cause on the right side there is text that can be on 1 or on 2 lines.

Answer (score 0):

I have updated your jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/gdggo6x5/1/)

You need to have height of the div and make parent div's property as below

```
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: middle;
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: I can't use min-hight? What if the text in there is dynamically so that the hight can change? (That is more to know it for the future, in this case text is fixed)

Comment: You can use `height:100%` and use padding to achieve what you are looking forward. You can check the same at http://jsfiddle.net/gdggo6x5/2/

Comment: hmm ok. I still don't get the middle text to middle.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should help you.

1. remove `float: left` and `float: right` from your `.footer2_block2` and `.footer2_block1` respectively.

You mentioned that you need float for lower resoution, but this whole solution will still help you there.

2. add following css in both `.footer2_block2` and `.footer2_block1` divs:

`display: inline-block; 
 vertical-align: middle;
 width: 100%;`

3. Change `width: 66%;` to `max-width: 66%;` for `.footer2_block1`; and `width: 33%;` to `max-width: 33%;` for `.footer2_block2` in css
4. Move `<div class="footer2_block2">...</div>` html on top of `<div class="footer2_block1">...</div>` in your html code.